# Could not exec dpkg! E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm using 12.04. I'm unable to perform any installation or remove because I lost my `dpkg` at `/usr/bin/dpkg`.

I tried with following procedure:

```
mkdir /tmp/dpkg
cd /tmp/dpkg
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.15.5.6ubuntu4_i386.deb
ar x dpkg*.deb data.tar.gz
tar xfvz data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg
sudo cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/
sudo apt-get update
```

But I got an error after running that `wget` command:

```
tar xfvz data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg

tar (child): data.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The next folders will be overwritten:

> etc  sbin  usr  var

so try:

`tar -zxvf data.tar.gz -C /`

Comment: hi ruslan..but,  i got the same error with this tar -zxvf data.tar.gz -C /

Comment: `md5sum dpkg_1.15.5.6ubuntu4_i386.deb` gives for me
`04d8f97f7c3b8e60f825a33b7c20649a` and is yours the same ?

Comment: md5sum dpkg_1.15.5.6ubuntu4_i386.deb.. i want to install this package or..                                                                 but, when i use that above procedure          wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.15.5.6ubuntu4_i386.deb

Comment: You didn't understand, you got something from the net, are you sure you have not corrupted file? For this `md5sum` exists. Could you please check. I am asking not simply, your file can be damaged. I could extract the same file without problem, so you have my md5sum, what's yours? No worries

Comment: i don't have much idea on this.. but, after 
 
md5sum dpkg_1.15.5.6ubuntu4_i386.deb .i try with this then i got two files like  6e3e7aa02298a0a940734dff4e8ff2ec  dpkg_1.15.5.6ubuntu4_i386.deb.gz

Comment: you have wrong check sum, I know it, because I downloaded the same file from the place you posted, that makes me think you downloaded corrupted file - could you please download and try again?

Comment: yes, after doing this  md5sum dpkg_1.15.5.6ubuntu4_i386.deb 04d8f97f7c3b8e60f825a33b7c20649a  dpkg_1.15.5.6ubuntu4_i386.deb
i got the same   .. what can i do with those

Comment: hello ruslan are you there. i need your help for finding that..can you find out what it could be.

Comment: Hopefully after you downloaded it right it should work.

Comment: no i m not getting. still it occurs .can anyone help me